# Create bat from java code keeping apostrophes and accented characters

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have created a java gui to generate bat files.
When I write the bat containing a string like this: "L’uomo più forte" notepad++ shows this: "L?uomo pi— forte"

Here is the code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(bat);
Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "Cp850"));
String stringa = "L’uomo più forte"
w.write(stringa);
w.write("\n");
w.write("pause");
w.write("\n");
w.flush();
w.close();
```

I had to use cp850 for dos use. Using base charset the bat give error.

Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **"Cp850"**:

```
Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "Cp850"));
```

Try using **"UTF-8"**:

```
Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
```

For more information on UTF-8 Encoding [Go Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm).

Don't forget to place a semicolon (**;**) at the end of your **stringa** string variable declaration/initialization and surround your code in **try/catch** block to handle possible **FileNotFoundException**, **UnsupportedEncodingException**, and **IOException** Exceptions.

**Also**...for NotePad, to provide a new line you need to also supply the **\r** tag:

```
w.write("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

- Open a cmd.exe command prompt session.
- Execute `echo L’uomo più forte>text.txt` command.
- Open `text.txt` file and copy the string there.
- Paste it in your code.

For example, I created the text.txt file, renamed it to `test.bat` and appended an `echo` command. This is my `test.bat` file:

```
@echo off

echo L'uomo pi— forte
```

... and this is the output:

```
L'uomo più forte
```

If some character is not displayed correctly, then the code page used does not contain such a character.

**Note**: I suggest you to use the standard Windows Notepad. The notepad++ program may cause strange output in these cases.